# Blender 2.82a renders 48 frames, but they're all frame 1

Tags: rendering, animation

This is just a short animation, keyframes are in an action, moving the play-head shows the animation in the 3d viewport, but when rendering the animation i get a 48 frame mkv/avi/etc. file consisting of only frame 1 over the entire duration, the same happens when rendering to any sequence format (no difference using Eevee or Cycles).

The odd thing is, if i append to certain other files, it animates just fine. Not all other files, just certain ones.

I've double checked frame start, end, step, and any other thing that i could think of, but no luck. Also checked all posts here, as well as other forums.

Has anybody run across something like this before?

Here is a link to the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vZod5z_Cm_DjkC0KC-mGATUpIi3lACKG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should share a file so someone can take a look and help you to see what's wrong

Comment: Your file is huge. Please try the following. (1) delete everything (2) add a camera (3) add an emissive cube (4) animate the cube to confirm movement. Then render that. if the problem persists, please upload **that** file (should be less than 1 mb)